# Qt, QNetworkAccess Manager download large files fail frequently

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply

I am using the following code to download some video files through LAN.

```
    QString url = "http://192.168.1.100/disk/IPCAMERA/" + downloadlist[downloadID];
    QNetworkRequest newRequest(url);
    QString concatenated = "admin:admin";
    QByteArray data = concatenated.toLocal8Bit().toBase64();
    QString headerData = "Basic " + data;
    newRequest.setRawHeader("Authorization", headerData.toLocal8Bit());
    newRequest.setUrl(url);

    reply = networkManager->get(newRequest);
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(refStateChanged()), Qt::UniqueConnection);
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)), this, SLOT(replyDownloadProgress(qint64, qint64)));
```

However, the downloading frequently fails, when the reply finished signal is triggered, it does not actually finished downloading the file but only part of it. What could I do to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

**It seems you should get the file size first**

QNetworkReply* reply = manager->head(newRequest);

Comment: Another point                                                              `file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append)`

Answer (score 0):

every reply is part of the Bytearray,you must add this connect:

```
connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(SlotReadyRead()));
void ClassName::SlotReadyRead()
{
if (_file)   //you must define QFile _file........
_file->write(_reply->readAll());
}
```

then, you will downloading the complete file.
Good luck!